# How do we accept a file in post request and upload it to mysql in Adonis JS?

Tags: adonis.js

I am creating an application to upload documents. The front-end is in Angular and the backend is Adonis JS. I am not able to get how we accept files from post request and upload them to MySQL using this framework.
I have looked through the documentation but nothing there.
Can someone help me with a simple code snippet highlighting how we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used get-stream and found it far easier than multer. This is my server side code.

```
Route.post("/api/profilePic/set", async ({
 request,
 response
}) => {

 try {
  let myUserId = request.get().userId;

  request.multipart.file("pic", {}, async file => {

   const fileContent = await getStream.buffer(file.stream);
   const profilePic = new ProfilePic();
   profilePic.userId = myUserId;
   profilePic.pic = fileContent;

   const isAvailable = await ProfilePic.findBy("userId", myUserId);
   const picSaveResponse = isAvailable ?
    await Database.table("profile_pics")
    .where("userId", "=", myUserId)
    .update({
     pic: fileContent
    }) :
    await profilePic.save();
  });
  await request.multipart.process();
    response.status(200).json({
    message: "Pic Updation success !",
    data: null
   }
  });
 } catch (err) {
  response.status(500).json({
    message: "Pic Updation failed !",
    data: null
   }
  });


});
```

Also, just to complete the answer, this is how i sent the request from my Angular client.

```
saveProfilePic(reqst) {
    // the request object has userId and pic
    let blob = new Blob([reqst.pic], { type: 'image/png' });
    const file = new File([blob], 'profilePic.png');

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pic', file, 'profilePic.png');

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multi-part/form-data');

    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('userId', reqst.userId);
    // params goes as the third parameter
    return this.httpClient.post(UrlConstants.SAVE_PROFILE_PIC, formData, { params, headers: headers });
}
```

Comment: i don't understand why in the Catch, you return success?. could you explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be using Multer, Adonis only comes with bodyParser which cannot handle file inputs. Please read https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer